# Printer holds jobs (Samsung M2070W + Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, samsung

My Samsung printer sometimes takes up to 45 minutes to print a page. When pluged in and out, it prints immediately for a while. After leaving it to to go power-saving mode, it sometimes can but mostly does not print immidiately after sending a document.

It's been installed well and the scanner works fine - Samsung M2070 wireless running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

When I open the printing jobs, I get the "processing" status.

[image: Whenever the printer stalls, I can see this processing message.]

How can I do something about it? I've tried removing the printer and installing it using Linux designated drivers, but the same thing happened again.

Here's the lpstat output:

```
gaj@gaj-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ lpstat -a
M2070 accepting requests since Sat 19 Oct 2019 08:51:30 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_ accepting requests since Fri 20 Sep 2019 10:42:15 CEST
```

Here's the complete lpstat output:

```
lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: M2070
device for M2070: dnssd://Samsung%20M2070%20Series%20(SEC8425197991A6)._printer._tcp.local/
device for Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_: ipp://SEC8425197991A6.local:631/ipp/print
M2070 accepting requests since Sat 19 Oct 2019 08:51:30 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_ accepting requests since Fri 20 Sep 2019 10:42:15 CEST
printer M2070 now printing M2070-651.  enabled since Sat 19 Oct 2019 08:51:30 CEST
    Unable to locate printer.
printer Samsung_M2070_Series_SEC8425197991A6_ is idle.  enabled since Fri 20 Sep 2019 10:42:15 CEST
M2070-651               gaj            9084928   Sat 19 Oct 2019 08:48:36 CEST
```

EDIT 1: I've also tried to add it to Google Cloud printing and it works, but it the same manner as above.

EDIT 2: Whenever the printer is installed, I get these two in Printers, but it's the same printer and when I go to printing in a PDF document, only M2070 appears. 
[image]

EDIT 3:
The error that sometimes appears in the printing window is "unable to locate printer".

[image: The error appears after a while. Nevertheless, the page is printer some time later]

Comment: Can you set a static ip for the printer?

Comment: I'm not sure where/how to do this. The printer doesn't have that option in its menu.

Comment: did you see, this very old bugreport? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/973270

Comment: @Mookey for IP , check `ping SEC8425197991A6.local` if it responds quickly. IP settings explained starting from  p137 & p148 in the User Guide

Comment: @Mookey Check its firmware version, last is V3.xx.01.37 . there were some bug fixed before for "connection fail after sleep mode" . Probably need Windows to run update, you may use a virtualbox.